# SQL SELECT statement with Image column slow

Tags: sql, image, select

I'm running a SELECT query in SSMS and it takes a very long time to finish. More than 30 minutes.

There is a Image column in the SELECT clause, and as soon as I remove that, the query runs normal.

Now I can see other forums firtsly state that you should not use the Image datatype for several reasons, and I agree.  But this database have it (15 years old), and I cannot change it now.  Also, there is some fairly big images in that column (> 20MB).

There are approx 8000 records to retrieve.

Any pointers on how to increase the performance when the Image is in the SELECT clause?  Indexes, views, ...?

Eg:

```
SELECT ID, Title, MyImageColumn
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: please don't store images in DB, just store its path.Then everything will be fine.

Comment: Problem appears with storage IO because of loading big data, you should use some kind of cache or add the speed to your storage.

Comment: Thanks sunleo, but as mentioned I already know that but I cannot change it for this database.

Comment: How many images do you want to retrieve at once? And what is the average size of those images?

Comment: I forgot to add the number of records.  There are 8000.  Average size about 5MB.

Comment: Aret: how do I use "some kind of cache or add the speed to your storage"?  Not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

It seems this is a Disk I/O related issue. The SQL Server reads the image's binary data from disk, and this hits query performance (it takes time to read 8000*5MB from disk).

You can move your table with the images to a faster disk array or to SSD storages by moving it to a new filegroup. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175905.aspx)
This could give you minor performace gaint.

Depending on the count ant total size of images you retrieve from the table at once, you should consider to query the info about the images in one query. After that, you should query only the binary data (one image per query) when it is really necessary.

Do you really need to query all records (with image data) at once? If not, than limit your results (use pagination to iterate throught the images stored in the database) or query only the non-binary data, and query image data when it is really necessary (and possibly add some kind of caching in your application).

Try to limit the number of records to a reasonable size when you query image or large binary data.

If you are using SQL Server 2008 or later, you should test if using `FILESTREAM` provides some performance gain or not.

The `IMAGE` datatype is depricated. Try to change it to `VARBINARY(MAX)`
 and read this article about [`Row-Overflow Considerations`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186981.aspx)

I know that you are mentioned that you can not move your files outside of the database, but this is your best chance and a best practice. Try to get a timeframe from your bosses to implement it.